# Bash - проверка на нахождение пользователя в домашней директории

Tags: bash

Необходимо выполнить проверку:
Если скрипт выполнен в домашней директории,вывести на экран путь к этой директории и выйти с кодом 0. В противном случае вывести сообщение об ошибке и выйти с кодом 1.
Вот мой скрипт.

```
#!/bin/bash

if "$PWD" == "$HOME"
then echo "$PWD"
exit 1
else echo "Error"
exit 0
fi
```

При выполнении не из домашней директории выводит ошибку.

```
saibo@LAPTOP-7L1650FJ ~/lab1
$ ./script6.bash
./script6.bash: строка 3: /home/saibo/lab1: Is a directory
Error
```

При выполнении из домашней директории выводит точно такую же ошибку.

```
saibo@LAPTOP-7L1650FJ ~
$ lab1/script6.bash

lab1/script6.bash: строка 3: /home/saibo: Is a directory
Error
```

Вопрос в том, как задать условие "является ли данное "местоположение" моей домашней директорией или же нет".

Comment: А где скрипт лежит? Я обычно добавляю переменную ABS_PATH="$(dirname $(realpath "$0"))", через нее можно строить ииерархию от запускаемого скрипта.

Comment: @Hellseher, *dirname* можно не использовать, а заменить на соответствующее преобразование *$0*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Просто сравнивать строки нужно чуть иначе:

```
if [[ $PWD == $HOME ]]
then echo "$PWD"
exit 1
else echo "Error"
exit 0
fi
```